# Xcode: How do you export custom strings files to XLIFF

Tags: xcode, localization, localizable.strings, xliff

I have added a custom strings file to use for a specific set of localized strings to my project which is used based on programmatic keys rather than explicitly declared keys (i.e. using the bundle's localizedStringForKey with a key that is generated from some variables instead of NSLocalizedString with a static key value).

I would like to generate an XLIFF from this file, preferably when using "Export for Localizations...". When I export it appears to only generate XLIFF for strings in code or interface and doesn't include my custom strings file content.